# using "AND" operator in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something like this:

```
@photos = Photo.where(:user_id => @user.id)
```

I want something like:

```
@photos = Photo.where(:user_id => @user.id, :public => 1)
```

However this does not work. I cannot find how to use the "AND" operator

Comment: what is your database? activerecord?

Comment: @Stefan is right. Your code is the simple way to make AND queries. It should work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution should work:

```
Photo.where(user_id: @user.id, public: 1)
```

Generates a query like this (assuming MySQL and a `@user.id` of 5):

```
SELECT `photos`.* FROM `photos` WHERE ((`photos`.`user_id` = 5 AND `photos`.`public` = 1))
```

I suspect that `public` is a boolean field and depending on your database adapter, `true` and `false` can either be stored as `1` and `0` or as `t` and `f`.

Try to pass a boolean value instead and let Rails handle the conversion:

```
Photo.where(user_id: @user.id, public: true)
```

It's even easier if you set up associations and some scopes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :public, -> { where(public: true) }
  scope :private, -> { where(public: false) }
end
```

Now you can fetch a user's photos with:

```
@user.photos.public   # user's public photos
@user.photos.private  # user's private photos
```

Answer (score 2):

Databases do not always store boolean values as `1` or `0`.
So ActiveRecord normalizes that and only recognizes `true` and `false` (or `nil`) when using hash conditions.

All these queries are equivalent:

```
@photos = Photo.where("user_id = ? AND public = ?", @user.id, 1)
@photos = Photo.where(user_id: @user.id, public: true)
@photos = Photo.where(user: @user, public: true)
```

But it is generally preferred to write it like that:

```
@photos = @user.photos.where(public: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
@photos = Photo.where("user_id = ? AND public = ?", @user_id, 1)
```

Active record [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) will help you.

Comment: What's the difference to the OP's query?